# live plot in c++ using gnuPlot

Tags: c++, plot, gnuplot

I want to plot given data in c++ using `gnuplot`. To do this, I developed a class

`gnuplot.hpp`

```
#ifndef GNUPLOT_HPP
#define GNUPLOT_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class gnuplot
{
  public:
    gnuplot();

    ~gnuplot();

    void plot(const T off_A, const int& iterationNumber);

    static int plottingCall;
};

#endif
```

`gnuplot.cc`

```
#include "../includes/gnuplot.hpp"


template<class T>
int gnuplot<T>::plottingCall = 0;


template<class T>
gnuplot<T>::gnuplot()
{
  std::string gnuplot;
}


template<class T>
gnuplot<T>::~gnuplot()
{
   system("rm -f ./data/data.dat");
   system("rm -f ./data/plot.gnu");
}

template<class T>
void gnuplot<T>::plot(const T off_A, const int& iterationNumber)
{
   gnuplot<T>::plottingCall++;
   std::string dataFile = "./data/data.dat";
   std::string gnuplotFile = "./data/plot.gnu";

   std::ofstream dataFileStream(dataFile);
   std::ofstream gplotFileStream(gnuplotFile);
   
   dataFileStream.open(dataFile, std::ios::app);

   if (!dataFileStream.is_open() || !gplotFileStream.is_open()) 
   {
      std::cerr << "==> Gnuplot class, File(s) failed to open" << std::endl;
      exit(0);
   }

   dataFileStream << iterationNumber << " " << off_A << "\n" ;

   if (gnuplot<T>::plottingCall == 1)
   {
     std::cout << "==> plotting" << std::endl;
     std::ostringstream gnuplot;

     gnuplot << "set output './data/off_A.png'\n";
     gnuplot << "set terminal png\n";
     gnuplot << "set title \"off(A) vs. number of iteration in SYMMEIG algorithm\"\n";
     gnuplot << "set xlabel \"iteration number  \" \n";
     gnuplot << "set ylabel \"off(A) \" \n";
     gnuplot << "set terminal png size 1024,768\n";
     gnuplot << "set palette rgb 33,13,10\n";
     gnuplot << "plot \"" << dataFile << "\" u 1:2 with linespoint\n";
//     gnuplot << "set terminal x11\n";
//     gnuplot << "set output\n";
     gnuplot << "pause 1\n";
     gnuplot << "reread\n";

     std::string cmdStr = gnuplot.str();
     gplotFileStream << cmdStr;
     system("gnuplot ./data/plot.gnu");
   } 

   dataFileStream.close();
}
```

`main.cc`

```
#include "./includes/gnuplot.hpp"
#include "./src/gnuplot.cc"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  gnuplot<float> gplot = gnuplot<T>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    gplot.plot(i*0.5,i);
  }
}
```

But when I compile and run the code, nothing is plotted, and `data.dat` is also empty. What is the source of problem in the class. I guess `ofstream` object is not properly defined.

Comment: Each time you want to add one point to be drawn, it seems you are opening and closing all files. At least be sure the files are opened in "add mode"

Comment: `dataFileStream.open(dataFile, std::ios::app);` by this command I append data to exsiting `data.dat`. You mean like this or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this line. I focussed on `std::ofstream dataFileStream(dataFile);`. Here, you open the file, in creation mode, and then you reopen it in add mode, without having even closed it. I am not sure what the result should be, but I am not very confident.

Comment: But I also close it by `dataFileStream.close();` ate the end of member function `plot`

Comment: Yes, but a problem is that you are opening it twice before, in two different modes

Comment: Gnuplot cannot "reread" from piped input. Did you mean "replot"?

Comment: the problem I encounter with `replot` is it continuously plots new graph in a new window. but I want to update the current window.